# Не все слово в тексте заменились используя метода класса String

Tags: java, строки

Мне удалось заменить слово **Hello** на звезды: `*`, но не все заменилось.

Вот Код:

```java
        String text = "Hello Java Programmers Hello Bad Hello World Hello Hello";
        String word = "Hello";
        int wordPos = text.indexOf(word);
        if (wordPos > -1) {
                String star = "*".repeat((word.length()));
                int allStar = wordPos + word.length();
                text = text.substring(0, wordPos) + star + text.substring(allStar);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(text);
```

Результат:

`***** Java Programmers Hello Bad Hello World Hello Hello`

Если кто-то знает, как решить эту проблему - спасибо заранее!))

Comment: а в чём проблема?

Comment: то что нужно заменить все слово hello на *****

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как заменить слово Java в строке используя substring?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1355215/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-java-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-substring)

Comment: Так у вас уже была решена эта проблема в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1355342/386633) на [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1355215/), методы `maskAllWords` / `maskWordRegex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи метода `replace`, Вы можете заменить слово в строке на необходимую вам строку/символ. Под Ваше ТЗ я подготовил код ниже

```
    public String replaceWord(String s, String word, char symbol) {
        return s.replace(word, String.valueOf(symbol).repeat(word.length()));
    }
```

Использование:

```
text = replaceWord(text, "Hello", '*');
//TODO
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод replaceAll() — заменяет каждую подстроку данной строки, которая соответствует заданному регулярному выражению, с данной заменой, другими словами — метод позволяет заменить слово в строке.

```java
String text = "Hello Java Programmers Hello Bad Hello World Hello Hello";
//                          что меняем | на что меняем
String result = text.replaceAll("Hello","****");

System.out.println(result);
// вывод - **** Java Programmers **** Bad **** World **** ****
```

Comment: Замену из звёздочек следует "строить" в зависимости от длины слова, сейчас у вас применятеся жёсткий код для замены `Hello` на `*****` -- нет даже параметра `word`.

Comment: @Alex Rudenko я конечно могу ошибаться в своём ответе, но он написал в комментарии `то что нужно заменить все слово hello на ***** – Bexoultan 2 часа назад`   я это понимаю как - заменить каждое слово helo на определённое количество звёздочек. а додумывать самому дополнительные условия типа - в зависимости от длины слова или в зависимости от фазы луны некорректно...

Comment: Разумеется, вы совершенно правы по существу вопроса, и имели полное право проигнорировать код в вопросе, как автор проигнорировал код в ответе, принятом 29 ноября.  Кроме того, воспользовавшись вашим решением, автор вопроса сможет запостить ещё множество _полезных_ задач из разряда: почему при замене `Bad` вставляется 5 звездочек, как сделать, чтобы при замене `Programmers` вставлялось 11 звездочек и т.п.

Comment: @Alex Rudenko ) так откуда мне знать предысторию его вопросов и точный вопрос задания?  он задал вопрос, и опираясь на него, я предложил свой вариант решения... из этого вывод - надо конкретней формулировать задание и вопрос